# #id in css is not working while element#\#id works why? and also general css doesn't affect element#\#id element while it should

Tags: html, css

#hex{ } is not working ( have tried edge, chrome, opera works nowhere) while img#/#hex{}(which i found from **chrome developer tools** works everywhere)

here is my html code:

```
<img src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbs/240/apple/118/bacon_1f953.png" alt="bacon-img">
<img id="#hex" src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/apple/325/broccoli_1f966.png" alt="broccoli-img">
```

here is my css code that doesn't work even if i tried `img#hex`  or simply `#hex`

```
img{
    background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.445);
    border-radius: 20px;
}

img:hover{
    background-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 25px;

 
#hex{
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.445) ;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

here is my css code that works partially: as hover dosen't work on `img#\#hex`
However, I do not know how `img#\#hex` works or why does it work.

```
img{
    background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.445);
    border-radius: 20px;
}

img:hover{
    background-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 25px;

 
img#\#hex {
    background-color: rgba(238, 255, 0, 0.445) ;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

img 1 what is when it is not hovered[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDgOs.png)

img 2 when hovered on first img [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGNSZ.png)

img 3 when hovered over second img [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oz79j.png)

have I made some mistake somewhere or is there some problem in my code here or anything of that sort?
please tell me.
thank you in advance!

i was expecting `:hover` 
to

work with `img#\#hex`

and give a transparent background while hovering!

Comment: Remove the `#` from your `id` attribute on your HTML elements. That's how you denote an ID in CSS, not in HTML. IDs should just be a plain word, such as: `<p id="some-id"></p>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#` in css is a selector for ID, to fix your code change the id of the image to `hex`.

And make the proper changes to fix your css selectors

```
<img id="hex" src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/apple/325/broccoli_1f966.png" alt="broccoli-img">
```

Also consider removing the `img` selector, as the `id` should be unique you do not need the `img` part.

```
#hex {
    background-color: rgba(238, 255, 0, 0.445) ;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the quick response and the query is partially solved! 
The :hover still doesn't work on the #hex why is that ?

Comment: The selector `#hex:hover` works for me in the CSS file, ensure that the id of the element is `hex` not `#hex`